# Problema com dropdown no menu

Tags: html, css

Quando se exibe os submenus ele está aumentado a altura do menu, o que eu quero é que ele sobreponha o menu ou qualquer outra coisa que estiver em baixo.

```
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    background: #1f1f1f;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #a32c2e;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.menu ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}

.menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

.menu ul li:hover {
    cursor: default;
}

.menu a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.menu:after,
.menu ul:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.menu>ul>li>a {
    line-height: 39px;
}

.menu ul li:hover>a,
.menu ul li.active>a {
    background: #a32c2e;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.active ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    display: none;
    background:#333;
    padding: 0;
    position: abosolute;
    width: auto;
}
.active ul li{
    position: relative;
}
.active:hover ul {
    display: flex;
}
```

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Tester</a>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub-2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub-3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i> Comunidade</a></li>
    <li><a href="/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i> Loja</a></li>

    <li style="float:right"><a href="/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i> Sair</a></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
   </nav>
```

[image: Este é o erro.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando `position: absolute` no segundo UL:

```
.menu li ul {
    position: absolute;
}
```

E retirando as margens dos ULs com `margin: 0`:

```
.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Assim você consegue o resultado que você espera.

```css
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    background: #1f1f1f;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #a32c2e;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
}

.menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

.menu ul li:hover {
    cursor: default;
}

.menu a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.menu:after,
.menu ul:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.menu>ul>li>a {
    line-height: 39px;
}

.menu ul li:hover>a,
.menu ul li.active>a {
    background: #a32c2e;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.menu ul ul {
    display: none;
    background:#333;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
}
.menu ul li{
    position: relative;
}
.menu li:hover ul {
    display: inline;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.menu li:hover ul a {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Tester</a>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub-2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub-3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i> Comunidade</a>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub-2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub-3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i> Loja</a></li>

    <li style="float:right"><a href="/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i> Sair</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
```

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, mas na segunda categoria do menu o dropbox bugou, você sabe o por que?

Comment: Os submenus foram pro lado ao invés de irem para baixo.

Comment: Fiz umas pequenas alterações no CSS, atualizei na resposta.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, mas gerou este problema http://prntscr.com/nn7q45

Comment: Tente usar um `z-index: 999` no .menu, creio que isso irá resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Basta adicionar

```
position: absolute;
```

Está asssim:

```
.active:hover ul {
    display: flex;
}
```

Vai ficar asssim:

```
.active:hover ul {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]